# using classes in scripts loaded from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a main page that includes my classes like this `require_once('../classes/init.php');`, on this page i have some ajax calls that loads a script into a `DIV`, but this content being loaded needs access to the classes I included from the main page, but when I try to access members of the class from within the script that I load dynamically, I get an error saying the class I am trying to access is undefined. Is there a way to get access to these classes from the dynamically loaded script?

Sample

main_site.php

```
  require_once('../classes/init.php');
  ......
  ..........
  <a>load script ClassXYZ into div</a>
  <div> ClassXYZ script loaded after user clicks on the anchor link above </div>
```

ClassXYZ.php

```
  $ClassXYZ = new Class();
  $ClassXYZ->doStuff();
```

Error 
Fatal error, ClassXYZ not found in........

ClassXYZ is declared in `../classes/init.php` file

Comment: What does jquery have to do with this? PHP runs on the server, it doesn't care what runs on the client to download it.

Comment: I'm afraid we simply do not understand what you're trying to do here and whether this is a server-side issue or a client-side issue.  Please clarify.

Comment: Are you trying to load PHP into a div and then execute it?  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jfriend00 just reading that last comment sounded wrong lol, turns out I had to use absolute path and require it within the file being loaded as well, but you must understand my confusion came from thinking that the classes that were loaded are accessible after the page has loaded >_< oh well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your approach should work.
Try to add require_once('../classes/init.php'); statement dynamically with the other code.

Comment: I will try that and see if it works, but I am using the `spl_autoload_register()` within the `init.php` file, so I figured it would have still worked.

Comment: Actually your approach is right, but I ended up having to use the absolute path -_-.... I hate when simple things cause such big problems, thanks for your tips